# Bad guy in a wheelchair with tubes and hoses in his body uses a computer to speak

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

Anyone remember a very, very old cartoon from Cartoon Network. I remember it was very grey, maybe even black and white, and weird. It had a kinda Matrix theme I think. The bad guy was in a wheel chair and could not move, used a computer to speak, and he had tubes and hoses in his body. It was a very weird cartoon.

Comment: How long ago did you watch the cartoon?

Comment: A long time ago, i would say 1997+ though the cartoon could be older than the date i was watching it. It was very grey themed or non-colour, i don`t remember very well.

Comment: Anyway the scary, weird grey atmosphere and the guy stuck in a wheel chair who had hoses in his body and was breathing with a mask i think is not something you forget easily.

Comment: Was I the only one who immediately thought of Stephen Hawking? :O

Comment: Stephen Hawking is one evil bastard. :)

Comment: Possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/188154/want-to-know-name-of-cartoon-show-where-the-characters-enter-a-virtual-world (which is newer)

Answer (score 8):

I believe you are looking for the villain [Jeremiah Surd](http://villains.wikia.com/wiki/Jeremiah_Surd), from the Cartoon Network show *The Real Adventures of Johnny Quest*

From the villians wikia:

> Bannon could never shoot an unarmed man and the two men were about to discuss a deal when the swat team that had come with Bannon shot Surd in the leg and neck. Bannon tried to stop them, but Surd's injuries were severe and he fell to the ground. Surd was furious and blamed Bannon for setting him up.
>
> Though not dead Surd was still paralysed from the shooting and had to spend the rest of his life in a wheelchair, he was sent to the Belle Isle Institute of the Insane in 1979

[image]

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for, wow, amazing, lost hope i would ever find it. As i`m born in `91 i was way to young to understand anything from it since it wasn`t the usual tom & jerry and popeye the sailor man. Now i can finaly rewatch it, thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like [*The Real Adventures of Jonny Quest*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Real_Adventures_of_Jonny_Quest), broadcast from 1996 to 1997. The villain you describe is [Jeremiah Surd](http://questworld.wikia.com/wiki/Jeremiah_Surd):

[image]