# Cartoon where the characters enter a virtual world where disabled father regains walking ability

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, virtual-worlds

I remember this one cartoon show on Cartoon Network, probably around year 2000.

There are some characters, but I remember his father was handicapped; he could not walk. They can all enter a virtual world by computer and some sci-fi glasses. And in there his father can walk, and they have some battles with virtual weapons.

I remember one episode where they found a pearl in the sea, which had some curse on it.

Comment: I was gonna come in here to say "Cyberchase", but that's on PBS and "Jonny Quest" seems to be the better fit anyway. Still a good show though if you've got little ones who are into this sort of thing.

Answer (score 9):

Sounds like **[*The Real Adventures of Jonny Quest.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Real_Adventures_of_Jonny_Quest)**

The show was originally aired from 1996 to 1997.

The paralyzed man, called Jeremiah Surd, is the main antagonist in several episodes and and the virtual world is called Questworld.

> A continuation of the Jonny Quest (1964)and The New Adventures of Jonny Quest (1986) series, it features teenage adventurers Jonny Quest, Hadji Singh, and Jessie Bannon as they accompany Dr. Benton Quest and bodyguard Race Bannon to investigate strange phenomena, legends, and mysteries in exotic locales. Action also takes place in the virtual realm of QuestWorld, a three-dimensional cyberspace domain rendered with computer animation.
>   [From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Real_Adventures_of_Jonny_Quest).

[image: Hadji, Jessie, and Jonny from the season one episode "Expedition to Khumbu"]

[image: Race and Surd fighting in QuestWorld from season two's "Cyberswitch"]