# Animated Series: Alien black spider robot crashes on Earth

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon, animated-series

I need help identifying a sci-fi animated series I remember watching at some point in the later '90s. I remember watching it on TV sometime around 1996-1998.

In the episode I saw a UFO/alien craft of some kind crashed somewhere on Earth. The alien aboard was some kind of large black spider-like robot.

At least one of the protagonists was a scientist (I believe working with the government). I think his title was either Dr. or Professor.

The government(?) recovered the craft, and held it in a kind of Area 51-like base in a hangar. Then at some point the spider-robot-alien escaped in the UFO.

They had to shoot down the UFO using some kind of special ray gun/machine gun turret. It was a massive gun turret that they had to wheel out. I remember the scientist (Dr. or Professor) operated the gun by sitting behind/beside the turret.

It was very urgent they shoot down the UFO before it escaped (I think), and at the end of the episode they were able to bring it down.

The main things I remember are the spider-like robot in the UFO, and the scientist using the advanced space gun turret at the end to shoot down the UFO.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this is MIB animated series form 1997-2001?

Comment: How can you remember so many details, 20 years after?

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/188154/cartoon-where-the-characters-enter-a-virtual-world-where-disabled-father-regains (about the 1990s series)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds like an episode of the original Johnny Quest....

The Robot Spy"  November 6, 1964
The Quest nemesis, Dr. Zin, sends a giant, cyclops, robot spider (by flying saucer-like craft) to a U.S. government research facility in the American Southwest to steal the secrets of a ray gun project on which Dr. Quest is working.

https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x20bx4i

Comment: Thank you! I've literally spent years looking for that. Can't believe it's actually from the 60s...it really felt like it was contemporary when I watched it as a kid so I always assumed it was a 90s cartoon. 

Though, looking at the episode now it's hard not to see some of the racist caricatures... Thanks again.

Comment: @sirwagalog Note that there was another Johnny Quest series, The Real Adventures of Johnny Quest, that aired in the 90s and featured the same spiders as a throwback. So it's possible you saw that one.