# 90s sci-fi series with an episode where a boy goes into VR and fights a Medusa-like monster

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, virtual-worlds

I am looking for an animated series, shown in the 90s. I remember an episode where the boy went into VR and fought a medusa-like monster. 
It may be that this was the premise for the whole series: That the children heroes go into VR every time to fight the evil guys.

I am not sure if the whole series were computer-animated but surely there were such elements together with classic animation.

The style of the series was quite dark and cool for teenage boys.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Check out the]suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for story-id questions to see if they help you recall any additional details you can]edit] into your question.

Comment: Dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/100755/bad-guy-in-a-wheelchair-with-tubes-and-hoses-in-his-body-uses-a-computer-to-spea/100759#100759, which is answered in a comment.

Comment: And maybe https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/188154/cartoon-where-the-characters-enter-a-virtual-world-where-disabled-father-regains?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you're thinking of the "[Heroes](https://jonnyquest.fandom.com/wiki/Heroes)" episode (Season 1, Episode 18) of *[The Real Adventures of Johnny Quest](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0115226/)*. Questworld, a VR simulation, was a common plot point, and [that episode](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0683575/?ref_=ttep_ep18) included a Medusa.

[image: Poster for "Heroes"]

### Medusa scene

Comment: you are awesome. thanks! but now that I see it again I think I was way too easily impressed as child with that computer animations back then :D

Comment: @ApostolisApo In fairness, it was pretty cool at the time. *Especially* for a half-hour children's serial. *RAoJQ* and *Reboot* were state of the art, just in an art that developed a lot soon after.

Comment: And it was definitely more of an adult take on the "kids get into wacky hijinx" than the original series. There were some really scary bad guys...